# Issue when using SolveWithGuess (Eigen 3.2.3)

Tags: eigen3

I would like to use the SolveWithGuess() function to solve a system of linear equations, starting from a good approximation. However, when I tried to do a test with an initial guess having small perturbations (`1.e-9*i; 0 <= i <= 20`) compared to the true solution, I received the following error values during the conjugate gradient iterations:

```
0   1.922e-09
1   3.694e-09
2   7.101e-09
3   1.365e-08
4   2.623e-08
5   5.043e-08
6   9.692e-08
7   1.863e-07
8   3.581e-07
9   6.882e-07
10  1.323e-06
```

Could you please what could be the problem? My test code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

void solve()
{
    int n = 20;
    typedef SparseMatrix<double, ColMajor> SM;
    typedef Matrix<double, -1, 1> DV;
    SM a(n,n);
    DV b(n), x(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = double(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) a.insert(i, j) = 0.0;
        a.coeffRef(i, n - i - 1) = 1.0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) x[i] = double(n - i - 1) + 1.e-9 * double(i);
    ConjugateGradient<SM> cg;
    cg.setMaxIterations(1);
    cg.compute(a);
    for (int it = 0; it < 100; it++)
    {
        cg.compute(a);
        x = cg.solveWithGuess(b,x);
        cout << it << "  " << scientific << setw(10) << setprecision(3) << cg.error() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eigen 3.2.x is very old. Can you try the most recent 3.3 version?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two problems: Your matrix is not positive definite, i.e., you should better use any of the other iterative solvers. But more importantly, if you set the maximum number of iterations to 1 and call `solveWithGuess` iteratively you actually do something like a gradient descent (i.e., it does not keep the previous search direction), which happens to behave terrible with your matrix.

If you are actually interested what happens "inside" an iterative solver, you need to insert debug-code into the corresponding `_solve_impl` method (or re-implement the solver accordingly)